# Backbone model extend only returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, salesforce

I'm trying to create a model for use with Smartstore/Smartsync, but the object is always returned as 'undefined'. What could be causing this? I can create ModelCollections, but not single Models. The models are in backbone, but I'm using AngularJS (see $rootScope object) to create them, if that matters. Type is just a string with the typename and fieldlist is an array of strings.

```
var model = Force.SObject.extend({
    sobjectType: type,
    fieldlist: function(method){return fields;},
    cache: function() { return $rootScope.CacheCollection[type + '_cache'];},
    cacheForOriginals: function() { return $rootScope.CacheCollection[type + '_cache_originals'];},
    cacheMode: function(method) {
        if (!$rootScope.OfflineTracker.isOnline()) {
            return Force.CACHE_MODE.CACHE_ONLY;
        }
        else {
            return (method == "read" ? Force.CACHE_MODE.CACHE_FIRST : Force.CACHE_MODE.SERVER_FIRST);
        }
    }
});
alert(JSON.stringify(model, null, 4));
return model;
```

Model is always undefined in the alert.

Comment: what is `Force.SObject`, does it extend from backbone model??

Comment: @bingjie2680 Yes, they are backbone models

Comment: then you need to instantiate it with the `new` Key. The model is a class(function).